# Azure - Where does web site store in RDP file system?

Tags: azure

I'm new to Windows Azure.

Currenlty I published a test website to Windows Azure. When I login to RDP, I see 
Local Disk (C:), Windows (D:), Local Disk (E:), Floppy Disk Drive (A:)

I'm wondering where my web folder is stored in file system. Am I missing something?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it's in `e:\sitesroot\0` -- if you have additional applications in the instance they'll be under `e:\sitesroot\1` and so on.

Note that this will change if you perform an upgrade: local drive E: will be removed and swapped with a new local drive F:. The next upgrade will swap back to E:, and so on.

Note also that these are internal details and absolutely shouldn't be relied on in your code. All is subject to change, I believe.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I do not see e:\sitesroot folder. I only see _rels, approot(only dll files), base, diagnostics, plugins, storage folders.

Comment: @Win - if you open up IIS Manager (Start > Run > inetmgr.exe) you can view your web applications and their file system location.